# Email template: Inside Linking

Tags: html, email, html-email

I have a HTML template for my emails, i wanted to know if its posible like to implement a menu, and the link redirect to the corresponding part of the content.

```
example: imagine the menu is: banna, apple, juice, coke.
and then the content goes: banna etcetcetc, apple etc etc etc...
make each one link to the exact content? thanks..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, sorry. What you're talking about requires some sort of conditional, and that would require a script. Most email clients strip your `<script>` and `<link>` tags. Unless you want to get your hands dirty with some server-side code like [gif sockets](https://github.com/videlalvaro/gifsockets) why not link to a little webpage where you can do any of those?

EDIT FROM COMMENTS

Thinking about it now.. Would hashtag linking work for you? Like clicking a link and having the scroll bar jump to that position? you can accomplish that with `<a name="linktotop">Other link will scroll to this</a>` and `<a href="#linktospot">Scroll!</a>` I just tested it in outlook.com and gmail and it seems to work. No promises on the other clients though.

Comment: yeah, i know anchor links can be done in normal html code, but wanted to know if it was posible in a email newslester... u totally sure it cant be done?

Comment: Thinking about it now.. Would hashtag linking work for you? Like clicking a link and having the scroll bar jump to that position?

you can accomplish that with `<a name="linktotop">Other link will scroll to this</a>` and `<a href="#linktospot">Scroll!</a>`

I just tested it in outlook.com and gmail and it seems to work. No promises on the other clients though.

Comment: really? can we use anchors in html email? would you mind telling me how, cuz i cant get it to work in gmail?

Comment: really? did it work on gmail? im using thunderbird and seems like isnt working on gmail...

Comment: yeah, how are you sending html emails? thunderbird lets you do that?